# Quick way of filling classes with values from datatable

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering if there was a quicker was to get a DataTable like this;

```
id  value1  value2
1   Hello   World
2   Foo     Bar
3   Test1   Test2
4   123     One
5   1       0
```

Into a class like this;

```
Public Class MyObj
    Public ID As Int32
    Public value1 As String
    Public value2 As String
```

I currently have this;

```
Dim myret As New List(Of MyObj)
If dt IsNot Nothing Then
        For value As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count
            Dim newObjAs New MyObj With {.ID = dt.Rows(value)("ID"), .value1 = dt.Rows(value)("value1"), .value2 = dt.Rows(value)("value2")}
            myret.Add(newObj)
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: There's all sorts of ways of doing this depending on your larger circumstances.  The search term you want is "map" or "mapping" data to objects.

Comment: Where does the data originate from? is it manually added to the datatable?